# Issue with multiple carousels in one page in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, jcarousel

I have a site where I need four different carousels on the same page. Each carousel has a different purpose with different items and different styles (height and width).

How can I go about getting this done? It seems to me there would be a CSS conflict issue with the `jquery.jcarousel.css` file.

How do I specify two different CSS files for each carousels with same skins?

Comment: I'm using jCarousel module for drupal 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! I defined overridden classes of my own with the help of firebug extension for Firefox and it worked.